# Inequality between $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+c}}$ and $\frac{3}{\sqrt[n]{1+(abc)^{1/3}}}$

Tags: inequality

Earlier

[Exploring an inequality between $\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c} $ and $\frac{3}{1+(abc)^{1/3}}$ if $a,b, c>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272376/exploring-an-inequality-between-frac11a-frac11b-frac11c-and)

the expressions $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+c}}$$ and $$\frac{3}{\sqrt[n]{1+(abc)^{1/3}}}$$ have been found to display two  inequalities for $n=1$ when $a,b,c \in [0,1]$ or in $[1,\infty)$.
Now the question is if there exist more general inequalities between them if $n>0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+e^x)^{1/n}}, n>0$. then $f''(x)=\frac{e^x(e^x -n)}{n^2(1+e^x)^{1/n+2}}>0,~ \mbox{if}~ e^x>n.$ Then Jensen's inequality
$$\frac{f{x}+f(y)+f(z)}{3} \ge f\left(\frac{x+y+z)}{3}\right)~~~~(1)$$ holds. So we have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+e^x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+e^y}}+
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+e^z}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+e^{(x+y+z)/3}}},~\mbox{if}~ e^x,e^y,e^z >n, n>0~~~~(2).$$ Hence, we can re-write it as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+c}} \ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[n]{1+(abc)^{1/3}}},~ \mbox{if}~ a,b,c>n,n>0.~~~~(3).$$
The sign of inequality(3) reverses if $0<a,b,c <n$. The equality holds when $a=b=c=n$.